Resize Leaflet map when its container is resized (dash plotly)
I'm having some issues with dash-leaflet; in particular with it's width when the parent container is resized. I'm using dash-resizable-panels to resize some divs.
Here's a MRE:
# pip install dash dash-leaflet dash-resizable-panels
import dash
import dash_leaflet as dl
from dash import html
from dash_resizable_panels import PanelGroup, Panel, PanelResizeHandle

handle = {"height": "100%", "width": "3px", "backgroundColor": "#51ada6"}
layout = html.Div([
    PanelGroup(id="panel-group", 
               children=[
                    Panel(id="panel-1",children=[html.Div([html.P("Dummy component")])]),
                    PanelResizeHandle(html.Div(style=handle)),
                    Panel(id="panel-2",
                          children=[
                            dl.Map(center=[45.81, 15.98], zoom=12, children=[
                                dl.TileLayer(),
                                dl.FeatureGroup([dl.EditControl()]),
                            ], style={'height': '100%', 'width': '100%'})]
                    )], direction="horizontal",),
], style={"height": "100vh"})

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = layout
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()

The initial layout is fine:

However, when I resize the map container I'm left with an un-rendered part of the map (gray part on the right) which looks like this:

Is there any way (be it through python or js) to resize or rerender the leaflet map when the container is resized so that the map fills (renders) the full width of its container?
SOLUTION:
app.clientside_callback(
        """
        function set_event(map_id) {

            // On resize event 
            var callback = function() {
                window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
            }

            new ResizeObserver(callback).observe(document.getElementById(map_id))

            return dash_clientside.no_update;
        }
        """,
        Output("map", "id"),
        Input("map", "id")
    )


If you dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')) in the browser console, the leaflet map should rerender properly. The thing is I don't know if there is a dash callback event for when the user moves the handle (the idea would be to run that code in a clientside callback), if there isn't, you can still add some js (create a .js file in your asset folder) that listens for the mousemove or mouseup event on the handle element (or you can use a MutationObserver to watch for specific changes being made), and in response, fire the resize event.

Thanks, I was able to solve it using your Event approach. I've added in the solution to the original question.

Don't post the answer in the question, create an answer with all the details instead and mark it as accepted so that other users can see this post as solved and more easily find it from SO search and search engines.

Couldn't find the answer button :D

SOLUTION:
app.clientside_callback(
        """
        function set_event(map_id) {

            // On resize event 
            var callback = function() {
                window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
            }

            new ResizeObserver(callback).observe(document.getElementById(map_id))

            return dash_clientside.no_update;
        }
        """,
        Output("map", "id"),
        Input("map", "id")
    )


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
